# Detect or prevent page load from object tag?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6, object-tag

I need to detect if a page is loaded from an `<object>` tag. On most browsers, several javascript iframe detection techniques flag this as an iframe (e.g. `window.top === window.self`), which is just fine.

The page is loaded via an object tag as such:

```
<object width="0" height="0" data="/target/"></object>
```

Some versions of Internet Explorer 6 are the exception (big surprise). The browser version is not controllable.
IE 6.0.2800 does not identify as an iframe, and will pass any expected width & height values along.

**EDIT**: If there is a way to have the target page break any loads from object tags (at least IE6, but any others would be okay), that would be fine with me.

Answer (score -2):

Does it really need to work under IE6 ? I mean...

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp ... IE only has 18.6% and people who use IE 6...

Comment: Well, if there was a way to have the target page break any loads from object tags (IE6 included along with any others), that would be fine with me.

Comment: Oh okay... I guess your the 1% exception then !

Comment: @DavidBélanger - Firstly, W3Schools' is not a good site to be recommending; in particular those stats are not representative of the wider internet (http://gs.statcounter.com/ is better, but no-one really has 100% accurate figures). Secondly: Yes, IE6 is old. Yes, people should stop using it. But some developers can't avoid supporting it, for whatever reason. If people are asking IE6-specific questions these days, it's generally because they have a specific need to support it. Telling them not to support it isn't helpful, unless you can also offer advice on how to migrate their users off it.